# Meteor: Using Jquery for creating dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm using jquery for creating dialog in my web application. In normal application, I can use jquery to done this task easily. But when moving to Meteor, it looks like Meteor has changed many things that normal javascript doesn't work. here is my code:

```
<template name="post_list">
    <button id="ask_question_btn">Ask A Question</button>
    <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title goes here...">Custom Dialog</div>
</template>
```

And here is corresponding javascript:

```
Template.post_list.events({
    'click #ask_question_btn': function(event, template) {
        template.$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    }
});
```

When I run, no thing shows. I don't know how to debug this. Please help me to fix this problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: Remove `template.` from `template.$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );` for just `$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );` You are already addressing the template since your are within `Template.post_list.events`. I bet that fixes it

Comment: No. I have changed as you said, but still no effect. thanks :)

Comment: $('#dialog') should at least return a jQuery object. Can you verify this is the case?

Comment: @IanJones How can I vertify this ? Thanks :)

Comment: @hqt console.log($('#dialog')) within the helper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the $.dialog() function is native to jQuery.  I'm familiar with the [jQuery UI dialog function](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), which you can include in your app by including any [jQuery UI package](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=jqueryUI) from Atmosphere.

Additionally, in your code, you'll need to initialize the dialog before opening.  I was able to get the following to work with the [mizzao:jquery-ui](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/jquery-ui) package:

```
meteor add mizzao:jquery-ui
```

then, in my helper file:

```
Template.post_list.rendered = function() { // initialize the dialog once rendered
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({autoOpen: false}); // autoOpen = false means this won't open until we ask it to
}

Template.post_list.events({
  'click #ask_question_btn': function(event, template) {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog('open');
  }
});
```

Hope that works for you. Let me know if you have any questions, I'm happy to help out.

Comment: thanks :) It's work. But there are something that I don't understand. 1) why do we need initialize dialog once rendered ? I have read on Jquery-ui guide that nowhere tell this. 2) Are there any differences between two packages `mizzao:jquery-ui` and `mizzao:jqueryui` ? 3) I have tested by download all jquery-ui library and put into js and stylesheet folder. Everything works fine. So are there any differences between two ways of use: use meteor package or put javascript libraries manually into project ? Thanks :)

Comment: @hqt 1) I don't see it mentioned explicitly anywhere in the documentation, but if you look at the examples (http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#entry-examples), you'll see that they initialize it.  Also, if you fail to do initialize it, you'll get an error in the console telling you that you need to do so. 
2) Not sure, but I don't think there's a difference.  The documentation for mizzao:jqueryui says "meteor add mizzao:jquery-ui" so I assume they're the same.
3) I think it's just convenience; using the package should couple it to your app so you don't have to install separately if you deploy.